# Getting Adf.ly hidden link with PHP

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm very new to stackoverflow and I'm trying to develop a script to grab actual hidden link from a shortened link.

What I want to know is, is there a way to get actual (final hidden) link from a adf.ly link with PHP or cURL?

```
function get_link($url){
  $redirect_url = null;
  if(function_exists("curl_init")){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $redirect_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    return $redirect_url;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: There are services out there that will do it.  Check out http://unshorten.it/api.php, http://www.unshorten.net/tips.php or http://unshort.me/api.html

Comment: Those are not working for Adf.ly but thank you :)